# C++ segfault at the end of a for loop

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault

This code is segfaulting and I can't really figure out why. When I use gdb it segfaults at the end of the function (the curly brace). So that doesn't really give me a lot of information as to what's going on. Here's the code, I'll provide extra info if needed.

```
typedef std::list<Ground> l_Ground;

void Player::y_collisions(l_Ground grounds) {
    for (l_Ground::const_iterator ent = grounds.begin(); ent != grounds.end(); ent++) {
        if (getGlobalBounds().intersects(ent->getGlobalBounds())) {
            in_air = false;
            velocity -= gravity;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Upon closer inspection, it's probably segfaulting at the end of that for loop. Which still doesn't really make sense because of the way the for loop is written. It shouldn't go beyond the end of the list.

EDIT2: This will work because of the answer below.

```
typedef std::list<Ground> l_Ground;

void Player::y_collisions(const l_Ground& grounds) {
    for (l_Ground::const_iterator ent = grounds.begin(); ent != grounds.end(); ent++) {
        if (getGlobalBounds().intersects(ent->getGlobalBounds())) {
            in_air = false;
            velocity -= gravity;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to the crash, but you really should pass `grounds` by const-reference.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I always forget to do that.

Comment: Ok I don't know why, but that fixed it. You should submit that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Note that you were not supposed to change the code in your question! Now we cannot see that the const& was missing!

Comment: Ok, I'll remove it. I changed it before I realized that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were passing the `grounds` parameter by value. That means a copy of the list was made. **Apparently your `Ground` class have a broken copy constructor**, which makes the `getGlobalBounds()` method referring to some invalid pointer, which caused the crash.

You should almost never pass a big object by value *unless* you want to immediately copy it. Always train yourself to type `const &` all the time :).

Comment: Yeah I didn't even write the copy constructor yet :P

Comment: The default copy constructor will work better, in many cases, than a broken implementation of your own copy constructor. However, if you have bare pointers in your class, then yes, you definitively need a copy operator.

Comment: Yeah I just started this project and haven't gotten around to doing that yet. I'm actually doing it now. I do have raw pointers so I'm going to need it sooner or later.